# Solidity-Type address not convertible to type uint256

Tags: solidity

I created an array of structures and then tried to get the values of each account of an array. But I failed with an array while passing the address variable which contains `msg.sender` and the type is not visibly convertible to `uint256`. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code, so we can see what you have tried so far. It's hard to tell where the Error may lies by now.

Answer (score 43):

As of Solidity v0.8, you can no longer cast explicitly from `address` to `uint256`.

You can now use:

```
uint256 i = uint256(uint160(msg.sender));
```

```
function f(address a) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  return uint256(uint160(a));
}
```

Comment: And in case you are dealing with an `address payable` you will have to cast away the payable as well.  Solidity (0.8.24) does not allow you to cast `address payable` directly to `uint160`, which is something I just ran into:
`uint256 i = uint256(uint160(address(some_payable_address)));`

Answer (score 6):

You can cast it explicitly:

```
uint256 i = uint256(msg.sender);
```

---

```
function f(address a) constant returns (uint256) {
    return uint256(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pre v0.8.0 of Solidity you could do:

```
pragma <0.8.0;

return address(toUint(item));
```

Post v0.8.0 of Solidity you must now do:

```
pragma ^0.8.0

return address(uint160(toUint(item)));
```

- References

`address(uint)` and `uint(address)`: converting both type-category and width. Replace this by `address(uint160(uint)` and `uint(uint160(address))` respectively.

> [see v0.8.0 breaking changes, Solidity Documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html?highlight=address%20initial)